CollectorMessage from Discord.js v.14 with SlashCommands
I got a problen trying to create a command about a "pokequiz" where you have to guess the pokemon's name using SlashCommand and Collectors. When the user types the correct answer, the bot does not send anything that is in the 'collect' event. Time simply passes and the bot sends the 'end' message. I tried using 'console.log' and in the console the bot doesn't send anything either.
const { EmbedBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const axios = require("axios");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("pokequiz")
    .setDescription('Muestra un Pokémon aleatorio para que adivines su nombre'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        try {
            const pokemonId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 898) + 1;
            const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`);
            const pokemon = response.data;

            // Preparar la Respuesta
            const pokemonName = pokemon.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1);
            const pokemonImage = pokemon.sprites.front_default;
            // Crear el Embed
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("¿Quién es ese Pokémon?")
            .setImage(pokemonImage)
            .setColor(0xFFCC00)

            // Enviar el Embed
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], fetchReply: true });
  
            // Filtro para respuestas del usuario que ejecutó el comando
            const filter = response => response.author.id === interaction.user.id;

            // Crear el collector para esperar la respuesta
            const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 10000 });

            collector.on('collect', message => {
                if (message.content.toLowerCase() === pokemonName.toLowerCase()) {
                interaction.followUp(`¡Correcto!  El Pokémon era ${pokemonName}.`);
                collector.stop('correct');
                } else {
                interaction.followUp('Incorrecto. Intenta de nuevo.');
                }
            });

            collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
                if (reason !== 'correct') {
                interaction.followUp(`Se acabó el tiempo. El Pokémon era **${pokemonName}**.`);
                }
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error en el comando pokemon-quiz:', error);
            await interaction.reply('Hubo un error al obtener la información del Pokémon.');
          }
    },
}

I would like it to be able to respond when the user answers correctly and when the user makes a mistake. I would also like the bot to be able to know if the user is in a quiz and if so, for the bot not to run another quiz.

what gateway intents do you have?
